# At what point in the parsing/rendering process do HTML elements get assigned a box model?

Tags: html, css, dom, cssom

Is it during the construction of the CSSOM (where possibly default padding/border/margin is applied to all nodes)?

Answer (score 2):

An element's box is (re)calculated in what is called the "*update layout*" phase, which is currently specified* as happening (at least) inside the next ["update the rendering"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering) step of the event-loop, at sub-step 14:

> 14. For each fully active Document doc in docs:
>
> - Recalculate styles and update layout for *doc*

but it can also be forced synchronously when calling [some getters](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a).

*<sub>Though this is a quite recent addition to the specs and not all browsers do follow it exactly, for instance I know from experience that to do this layout update Safari will not wait for the next "painting frame", but just some idle time.</sub>